# add libraries to VSCODE (linux), dont understand JSON files

Tags: c++, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, libraries

I'm trying to run a cpp program that needs the matplotlibcpp.h header and some libraries. I copied this header file and save it into my cpp file folder.
My matplotlib and python libraries are here:

```
 "/usr/include/eigen3",
  "/usr/include/python3.8"`
```

My problem is that when I compile the program it returns that nor matplotlibcpp.h and python.h exist and as far as I have being searching in internet is because paths are not linked. I have seen many solutions where they tell to edit the c_pp_properties.json and task.json files but, there is no explanation about why should I change that, and I dont understand (mainly, because my json code is not the same as other post answers)

Please can someone tell me what I have to do to compile properly my code? And explain me how and why do I have to edit those json files? I really don't understand anything

this is my include part in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>
#include "LSPB.h"
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;`
```

my task.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/include/eigen3",
            "/usr/include/python3.8"
        ],
        "group": {"kind": "build", "isDefault":true},
        "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

my_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "-I",
                "/usr/include/eigen3",
                "/usr/include/python3.8"

            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I just want to compile my program with no errors and learn how to use VSCODE when it comes to link libraries

Comment: Your args of your tasks.json are completely wrong. The comment is wrong as well. Your `my_cpp_properties.json` is also wrong.

Comment: You probably want to start over with this: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux)

Comment: Thanks, I followed the tutorial and solved my problems. both json where badly condigured